# chrome.runtime.onConnect doesn't exist in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in a persistent background script (background.js):

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "knockknock");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        if (msg.joke == "Knock knock")
            port.postMessage({question: "Who's there?"});
        else if (msg.answer == "Madame")
            port.postMessage({question: "Madame who?"});
        else if (msg.answer == "Madame... Bovary")
            port.postMessage({question: "I don't get it."});
    });
});
```

and when I load/reload the extension in Chrome I get the error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
```

The code was taken right of the Chrome Extension's documentation site, so it's probably working code and there is just some setting I'm missing.

The manifest looks like:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TestMessaging",
    "version": "1",
    "background" : {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": [
                "contentscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The documentation appears to be wrong. `chrome.runtime.onConnect` is not defined (Chrome 25). You could use `chrome.extension.onConnect` instead (it can be triggered with `chrome.extension.connect`).

Comment: chrome.runtime.onConnect was added in Chrome 26 (it hit stable yesterday). Before that, you still have to use chrome.extension.onConnect.

Comment: @RobW THANK YOU! You just saved me a great deal of time. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chrome.extension.onConnect` instead (it can be triggered with `chrome.extension.connect`).